# Как вывести все товары пользователям которые они подавали

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица `table_products` и в нем есть столбец `login`.
Как сделать запрос чтобы пользователь видел какие он объявления подал?

Этот код выводит все товары всех пользователей. Этот код не правильный но думаю его надо просто доработать, только не знаю как

```html
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['auth'] == 'yes_auth') {
    include("include/config.php");
    include("functions/functions.php");
    $all_products = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE login='$login'",$connect);
    $result_count = mysql_num_rows($all_products);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вообщем вот, тут 10 объявлений 9 у админа 1 у евгена, если я захожу под admin то показываются все объявления как admin так и Евгена, а если под Евген то показывается как admina так и Eвгена. А мне надо чтобы у каждого логина свои объявления показывались. Вот вроде хорошо проблему описал

Comment: Для начала определитесь, откуда в таблице `table_products` берется `login`. Потом разберитесь, как вам php-скрипт должен понять, какой конкретно пользователь к нему пришел. Без этих двух условий ответ дать невозможно в принципе

Answer (score 1):

1. Не используйте расширение mysql, оно устарело, не поддерживается и не развивается. Используйте mysqli либо PDO
2. Почитайте немного про SQL. Вам надо в запросе указать условие выборки

В вашем случае

```
$login = "логин пользователя";
$all_products = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE login='$login'",$connect);
$result_count = mysql_num_rows($all_products);
```

По уму.

```
$login = "логин пользователя";
$db = new mysqli(данные для коннекта);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE login=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $login);
$stmt->execute();
$result_count = $stmt->get_result()->num_rows;
```

Comment: Пользователей очень много, для каждого писать замучаюсь)

Comment: @Евгений если вы про `$login`, то он у вас откуда то ведь приходит? Я его добавил для того, что бы было понятно, что в нем должно быть. Если про `$db = new mysqli(данные для коннекта);`, то инициализация делается один раз в самом начале, а потом используется по мере надобности.

Answer (score 1):

```
$login_products = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_products WHERE login='$login'",$connect);
```

Где $login - логин пользователя

Comment: Беда в том что пользователей много, и мне надо чтобы у каждого показывало свое

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы извлечь все записи из таблицы `table_products` соответствующие пользователю с логином 'user' в SQL-запрос следует добавить следующие WHERE-условие

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table_products
WHERE
  login = 'user'
```

PS Обратите внимание, что расширение mysql, которым вы пользуетесь признано устаревшим и уже исключено из PHP 7. Лучше ориентироваться на расширения mysqli или PDO.